# Maximum capacity that Dynamodb can scan at a time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

AWS describes

> a single Scan request can consume (1 MB page size / 4 KB item size) / 2 (eventually consistent reads) = 128 read operations.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html

128 seems to be the maximum capacity which Scan command can read at a time.

However, when I test, Scan command(eventually consistent, without any filter option) is always returned at 119.5 capacity though there are enough items to read.

Why does this mismatched figure come out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key word here is "can". From the documentation, they say "a single Scan request **can** consume ..."

This is their written limit, which means depending on the item size and other variants, the actual capacity will be different.

Comment: What factor do you mean more detail?Ok they are saying "can" but it "can not"  now. My item size is just a several 10bytes and 8 capacitiy is worth 64 kbytes(4k * 2 *8). It is not that small just to ignore.

Comment: @SangminKim your scan is costing you 8.5 (6.6%) *fewer* RCU than it potentially could.  This small discrepancy is probably related to page fill factor -- speaking of databases in general, not DynamoDB specifically, pages in a database are not typically filled to 100% because if they were, inserts and any update that caused the size of a record to increase could require a resource-intensive page split, since records do not span page boundaries. In short, DynamoDB is unlikely in most cases to have packed a full 1MiB of data into each 1MiB page.

Comment: Worth noting, I think: a completely different database platform with which I am familiar, InnoDB, uses a target page fill factor of 15/16... which is almost exactly the same ratio as the 119.5/128 you observed.  To me, this has the earmarks of being likely related to page fill.